# Deploying Qt Qml app to Windows 8 shows me a blank window

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, qml

I'm trying to deploy a QML app, but I keep getting a blank small window instead of my qml based window.

The things I've tried:

I added my qml in the resources, in Mac the deployment now works... but even if I copy the qml dir to my .exe dir, it doesn't work
I've copied the qwindows.dll to the platforms dir in my .exe dir
I've copied all the dependencies dll: icudt51.dll, icuin51.dll, icuuc51.dll, libEGL.dll, libGLESv2.dll, Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Gui.dll, Qt5Network.dll, Qt5Qml.dll, Qt5Quick.dll

I've tried copying the dirs: QtQml, QtQuick, QtQuick.2 to my .exe dir either.

Nothing changes

Then I've tried to run the .exe from the command line with env variable: QML_IMPORT_TRACE=1 and I see nothing :(

The Qt is 5.2, Windows 8, MSVC 2010
Anyone has any clue about what can be happening?

Comment: Show all the code and console output.

Comment: My .pro file: http://pastebin.com/NxzVDCf1
My resource file: http://pastebin.com/hBtNn9WL
My main.cpp: http://pastebin.com/KPQ38iiY

Comment: Running from inside Qt Creator, and if I run outside it, I don't see any output in the console, even with QML_IMPORT_TRACE = 1.

Comment: Does it work if you drop the resource usage for a trial?

Comment: "QML_IMPORT_PATH =" does not make much sense in your project file. Also why do you add the qml/EurecaSubtitlesConverter/main.qml file to the others if you are also trying to use resources?

Comment: No =/ I changed the view->setSource to set the local qml file instead of the resource one... nothing changed, the app runs fine inside Qt Creator, but I see only a blank window outside it.

Do you think remove the resource completely can make some difference?

Comment: Of course. Moreover, you should use full path for setSource. What happens if you do that? Also, please strive for a self-contained example, with one main.cpp and the qml files. Currently, you have more than one cpp.

Comment: "Also why do you add the qml/EurecaSubtitlesConverter/main.qml file to the others if you are also trying to use resources?"
That's because in the beginning it was in others.

Comment: If I use full path I get another error: "Couldn't find module "QtQuick.Controls 1.1"".
I suppose I need to copy something in my .exe dir that's is missing.

Comment: i've copied QtQuick structure (including subdir Controls) to my .exe dir, but nothing changed =/ Any other idea on this?

Comment: Yes, please provide a self-contained example.

Comment: Doing the self-contained example I found the problem, it was missing the Qt5Widgets.dll... the strange thing is that it didn't warn me about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it seem to have missed the Qt5Widgets.dll file