# Deploying Qt Qml App to Windows shows me a blank window

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, qt

After suffer with a lot of problems trying to deploy a Qt/Qml app to Windows 8, as I described in this question: [Deploying Qt Qml app to Windows 8 shows me a blank window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930605/deploying-qt-qml-app-to-windows-8-shows-me-a-blank-window)

I could make it work copying the Qt5Widgets.dll... but it was only working in my own development machine (installing it there, but yet my own machine).
Then I tried to install it in another machine (a VM running Windows 7).. and at first I got error of missing platform plugin... ok, I copied qwindows.dll to appDir/platforms, and it seems to resolved this problem.
But then I got another missing dlls errors (the ones related to VS2010), then I installed the Visual Studio 2010 redistributable package... ok, now the app starts, but with a blank window :(
The qml files and everything are in a resources file, so it should be in the binary.
And I've no idea where to go from there to find this issue.

Any idea what can I do? The weird thing is that it was installed fine in my own development machine.
And my conclusion is that deployment of Qt in OS X is much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem with these steps:

- check your qml files path. For example default generated code is the following:

  ```
  QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
  viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/test/main.qml"));
  ```

  So qmls should be in "qml/test" folder
- check the missing dlls:

  1. download VmMap tool from Windows Sysinternals suite (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533)
  2. compile and run your app in qt creator to get it working like it should
  3. run VmMap and open your running app's process.
  4. sort the lower window by 'Details' - so you'll see all loaded DLLs sorted by path.
  5. copy the missing dlls. It should work now!

Comment: I tried everything you said, but still same results:

I've installed VmMap in both machines (W8 development one and the W7 VM one) then I ran my application via Qt Creator, building and running, got a lot of new dlls, like qtquick2plugin.dll, dialogplugin.dll, etc.

Then I installed my app in my dev machine and found that the app was actually getting these dlls from Qt installation, good I thought, I just need to copy them in the installation.

Did it but same results in the VM installation, and VmMap doesn't show any of the missing dlls in the VM.

I still get a blank window, what I can do?

Comment: I tried to organize the directories according to what I see in VmMap, like qtquick2plugin.dll inside /<myappdir>/QtQuick.2/, qtiff.dll inside /<myappdir>/plugins/imageformats, tried imageformats inside /<myappdir>/imageformats/, etc, etc, etc... nothing seems to work :(

Why so hard to deploy Qml in Windows :(

Comment: Almost there... I followed this "hard way" deployment: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows
And it runs fine on W8(with Qt installation hidden), but crashes on W7 with an error in QtQuick: exception code: c0000005
Could a wrong VC redist package is causing that?

This error never happens in development or in W8.

Comment: Another differences between machines:
W8 is the development one, 64 bits and with VC 2010 installed.
W7 is a VM, 32 bits, and with vc 2010 redistributable package only.

Comment: So did you fix it ? Redistributable packages installed should match those Qt binaries' was built with. And there's also a qt.conf file (https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qt-conf.html) to point where the "plugins" folder is.

Comment: It's working in Win8, I tested in 3 machines with Win8 and it's fine... but it's not woking in the only one machine (actually a VM) I've with Win7... Redistributable package is the same for both, but the app crashes on start (at least it's not the blank window anymore).

For now I need to use the app in Win8 only.

Comment: Ok. Now you can use the visual studio debugger to solve the puzzle in Win7. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I've had also a lot of trouble deploying Qml apps with a blank window too.

In general this site gives useful hints:
https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html

The blank window issue was caused be two different things in my case:

1. The relative path to the qml files were not correct. I've solved this by storing the qml files in a resource file and then calling them from there.
2. It seems to be a problem if the application is located on a network drive. I haven't found a solution for that except copying the application to a local folder.

In general I think deploying is a big big pain :-/

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)
Really, very big pain to deploy it on windows :(

1 - I think this is not the problem, because I'm using a resource file, so it shouldn't be a problem, right?

2 - Not in a network drive :(

The only I think could be the problem is that in the beginning I was not using a resource file, then later I moved to the resource file... maybe I missed something in this transition?
My .pro file: http://pastebin.com/njqRrJxg
My resource file: http://pastebin.com/ntFVY8YY

Comment: What does your main function look like?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. Maybe you make another test: Just copy the whole content of the Qt\bin folder to your application, just to make sure you didn't forgot any required library or something else....

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try that and let you know.